# simple jquery fetch from mysql

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to use jQuery with MYSQL and I wrote something like this :

```
<html>

<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function example_ajax_request() {
  $('#example-placeholder').html('<p>Loading results ... <img src="ajax-loader.gif"  /></p>');
  $('#example-placeholder').load("loadres.php");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="query">
<select name="show"  id="box" >

 <option value="0">Select A Test</option>
 <option value="All">--All--</option>
 <option value="M1">Model1</option>
    </select>
<input type="button" onclick="example_ajax_request()" value="Click Me!" />
</div>
<div id="example-placeholder">
  <p>Placeholding text</p>
</div></body>
</html>
```

Basically I want to pass parameters to the `loadres.php` file. But unable to figure out the exact way to do.
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of parameters do you want to send and should this URL also be used for changing data? Depending on that you either have to use `GET` or `POST` to transmit your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#example-placeholder').load("loadres.php?show=" + $('#box option:selected').val());
```

This will use jquery to get the selected value from the drop down list and append it to the URL as a querystring parameter, which you can access in the loadres.php page.

Comment: This sample seems to work than others, but the issue I am facing now is if I try to pass parameters using `+`, when I try to capture it in the results page, I am not getting the `+` sign. Any idea why it is getting stripped off?
Ex : `loadres.php?show=one+two+three`

Comment: You need to understand URL character encoding.

Take a look at this: http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/urlEncoding/

Answer (score 3):

You should use the $.ajax() method from jQuery. you can pass data to the url and have a callback at the end.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'loader.php',
  data: 'somedata',
  type: 'GET',
  success: function(data){
    $('#example-placeholder').text(data);
  }
});
```

This will do the trick. This method also provides far more flexibility. You can have different functions such as error functions and complete functions.

Comment: minor details: 

the data attr should either be a query string "foo=bar&baz-boo" or a hash eg {key: value}

If you want to post the form elements as params you can do $("form").serialize() as well - that select element should be enclosed in a form

Answer (score 0):

similar to [saif-bechan's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/207633/saif-bechan) post you can use ajax with post and data can hold an object to pass multiple parameters

```
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: loadres.php,
        data: {
              foo:'bar',
              selected:$('#selector').val()
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        error: function(data) {
                   //error code here
        },
        success: function(data) {
                      //success code here
        }
    });
```

I will also note that is is better to put your click event in jquery context not in the html

so in script somewhere use

```
 $('#button_id').click(function(){
       //call to ajax
 };
```